# How can I replace dot in Bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, string, awk

I want to do something like this:

```
echo "abc edg.txt" | awk -F. '{print $0"---"$1}'
```

I expect the result should be:

> abc edg---txt

but it turns out to be:

> abc edg.txt---abc edg

What is causing this behavior, and how can I fix my code to produce the output that I expect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In awk, `$0` evaluates to the whole record, and field indexes are one-based.

You probably want to do:

```
$ echo "abc edg.txt" | awk -F. '{print $1"---"$2}'
abc edg---txt
```

Answer (score 12):

If you just want to replace the dot:

```
var="abc edg.txt"
echo ${var/./---}
```

Comment: Yes, this is simplest way to replace.  The question definitely asked how to 'split' when I answered!

Answer (score 3):

[Frédéric Hamidi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482225/how-can-i-split-a-string-by-dot-in-bash-shell/4482236#4482236) fixes your problem with `awk`, but since you asked about how to split a string by dot in Bash shell, here is an answer that does exactly that, without resorting to `awk`:

```
$ foo="abc edg.txt" ; IFS=. ; a=($foo) ; echo ${a[0]}---${a[1]}
abc edg---txt
```

It's even easier if you only want to split on the *last* '.' in the string:

```
$ foo="abc edg.txt" ; echo ${foo%.*}---${foo##*.}
abc edg---txt
```

Comment: You want `${foo%.*)` to strip off only the *last* dot and test

Answer (score 3):

`Awk` is great, but there are other ways to subsitute.

With `sed` you can get all of the dots and not only the first one.

```
echo "abc edg.txt" | sed 's/\./~~/g'
```

Out: `abc edg~~txt`

The expression `sed 's/\./~~/g'` is equivalent to "substitute `\.`(dot) with `~~`, globally".

```
variable="abc here.is.more.dot-separated text"
echo ${variable}| sed 's/\./~~/g'
```

Out: `abc here~~is~~more~~dot-separated text`